# Target every nth iteration of an element that has specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I know I cannot do this with CSS but I'm wondering, with jQuery, if it's possible to target every nth iteration of an element that has a specific class. So if I wanted to select every fourth `.media` element or every third `.media` item.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
</ul>

$('.layout-option--b .media').each(function() {
    $(this).filter(function(index, element) {
        return index % 4;
    }).addClass("fourth");
});
```

Comment: CSS4 was kicking around `:nth-match()` which would have provided a pure css solution.  However, it has become a scrapped feature.  Otherwise, `:nth-match(4n+4 of .media){ color: red;}` would have done the trick.  Until it becomes available or CSS allows the use of a class as a subset on `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()` javascript/jquery is the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use `filter()` for this and check elements index using `%`. Because `i` starts from 0 you can use `i + 1`.

```js
$('li.media').filter(function(i) {
  return (i + 1) % 4 == 0
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="element">Li</li>
  <li class="element">Li</li>
  <li class="element media">Li</li>
  <li class="element media">Li</li>
  <li class="element">Li</li>
  <li class="element media">Li</li>
  <li class="element">Li</li>
  <li class="element media">Li</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly.  In my case, I had my <li> elements in rows of 3, using jQuery to sort through based on category.  When users pick a new category, that category gets an "active" class.  I needed every 3rd (return i + 3) to clear and float left (based on css for the "active" class). All solutions I found were some iteration of using :nth-of-type, and they didn't work for me.  I highly recommend this answer, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out based on the index.

```js
$('ul .media').filter(function(i) {
  return (i + 1) % 4 == 0;
}).addClass('class')
```

```css
.class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
  <li class="element"></li>
  <li class="element media"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm guessing I cannot do this using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
$('.media').each(function() {
    i++;
    if (i%4==0) {
       $(this).addClass("fourth"); 
    }
});
```